# How to display saving amount if a product is on discount?

Tags: magento2

I am trying to display how much a customer will save when a product has a special price. I want to display it on the product page next to the special price or above it. I am attaching an image so you can see what exactly I am trying to achieve. I was not able to find anything similar to what I want to achieve. I am using Magento 2.3.2

[image: Price]